# Disabling text drag and drop in a text field using jquery

Tags: jquery

Can any one help in disabling drag and drop of text in a text field using jquery that works in Firefox and IE?

```
<input type="text"/>

$("input").draggable('disable');
```

I am using this piece of code for disabling drag on my particular text field element. It doesn't work. Also I need guidance for disabling text drop.

UPDATE:

Let me explain you the scenario. The text entered in a text field should not be draggable. That is the text should not be selected and dragged to another field. Also any text should should not be droppable to that text field. In general, the user has to type the text. No drag and drop.... I am not sure what code has to be used to prevent drag and drop.

Comment: Code ? Example ? Pictures ? anything ?

Comment: I believe @ManseUK is asking if you can post something to help illustrate your problem and the solution you're looking for.

Comment: @Colin sorry - I should have posted a proper comment - this is the second question(out of 3) from the OP where people have requested more detail .... so i decided to shorten my request !

Comment: @DilipBS what I was requesting was some code from you - the question above really doesnt mean a lot to most people - we have no idea what your HTML looks like - what you mean by drag and dropping text from a text area, what you have already written. If you want people to put effort in you need to at least demonstrate that you too are willing to put some effort in ....

Comment: <input type="text"/>$("input").draggable('disable');  I am using this piece of code for disabling drag on my particular text field element. It doesn't work. Also I need guidance for disabling text drop.

Comment: @ManseUK  Is it okay for you now?? Can you help me further??

Comment: @DilipBS where is the example or explanation of what you actually want ?? i have never heard of calling the `draggable()` method on an input field - what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @ManseUK Let me explain you the scenario. The text entered in a text field should not be draggable. That is the text should not be selected and dragged to another field. Also any text should should not be droppable to that text field. In general, the user has to type the text. No drag and drop.... I am not sure what code has to be used to prevent drag and drop.

Comment: @DilipBS Perfect - you explained exactly what you want to happen .... why didnt you put that in your question at the start ??

Comment: @ManseUK Oh yeah.. That was my mistake...

Answer (score -2):

I think you need this

`$("input").draggable({ disabled: true });`

From the documentation: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-disabled

Comment: Is there any other way so that it works fine in firefox and IE?

Comment: Not sure why this is being voted down?  I only corrected the OP with the proper syntax from the spec.

Comment: @JasonGennaro  I don't know why its voted down. I didn't do that... If you find a solution for my problem, pls let me know...